# Can Postgres be optimized by transferring values in binary?

Tags: postgresql

When writing an application that interfaces with Postgres using the C API,

In the normal course of events, data is transferred in text form. This makes sense for strings, but for types like `INTEGER`, `BIGINT` and `UUID`, which the database server internally handles in binary, it feels intuitively reasonable to suppose that bandwidth and server CPU cycles could be saved by reading and writing the binary form directly.

I have run some simple tests on the result of a `PQexec` of `SELECT`, with `INTEGER` and `UUID` fields. `PQfformat` returns 0 for those fields (indicating that they are in text, just like accompanying `VARCHAR` fields), and `PQgetvalue` unsurprisingly returns their values in text form.

Is there a way to read (and correspondingly write, with `INSERT`) such data in binary form? If so, does it actually improve performance? (I think it's necessary to double check that, apart from anything else, to make sure it doesn't end up in a scenario where data is passed in binary, but the underlying protocol ends up converting to text and back anyway.)

Comment: Interesting. Java does send ints, longs, doubles, and floats in binary form. I thought that C would be more prone to do so. Maybe the issue is with the driver itself, or its version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience says so using binary protocol for numbers has not too big benefit. The main benefit is for `bytea` or for some long values like geodata geometries. If you want to use binary format, you should to use function `PQexecParams` instead `PQexec`. There are an array `paramFormats` where you can mark possibly parameters in binary format, and `resultFormat`, where non zero specifies binary result.

The reason why Postgres uses text format by default is simple. Postgres is multiplatform database, and native binary format for numbers can be very different. Then Postgres uses own universal binary format, but the work with this format is little bit more complex, and little bit more CPU consuming. Unfortunately, you cannot to use native binary formats if you want to connect from PC client to AIX server.

If you want to implement fast import, use:

- disable autocommit,
- use prepared statements
- **use COPY command instead INSERT**